# How to call a Stored Procedure from Hibernate having both IN and OUT parameters

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, stored-procedures

I want to call a Stored Procedure from Hibernate which returns an out value. Here is my Stored Procedure.

```
create procedure myProcedure
(  
in in_Id int,  
out out_Id int  
)  
begin  
...  
END;
```

I am trying this to call my procedure

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(  
"CALL myProcedure(:in_Id)")  
.setParameter("in_id", 123);   
//Not sure how to register out parameters...??      
List result = query.list();
```

I tried everything but no luck. Can you help me please?
If i try the above it says:

> **Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE myProcedure; expected 2, got 1**

I tried to add an out parameter like

```
myProcedure(:out_id:in_Id)
```

but then it says

> **Not all named parameters have been set:**

I don't know how out parameter will be set? Is it like the following?

```
.setParameter("out_id", ?);
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: This post is very helpful! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347931/hibernate-calling-stored-procedure-returns-cursor

Answer (score 10):

Considering you have a simple stored procedure that outputs a basic type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE count_comments (
   IN postId INT, 
   OUT commentCount INT
) 
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO commentCount 
    FROM post_comment  
    WHERE post_comment.post_id = postId; 
END
```

You can call this stored procedure using a JPA [`StoredProcedureQuery`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-mysql-stored-procedures-and-functions-with-jpa-and-hibernate/):

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
    .createStoredProcedureQuery("count_comments")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("postId", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("commentCount", Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
    .setParameter("postId", 1L);
 
query.execute();
 
Long commentCount = (Long) query
    .getOutputParameterValue("commentCount");
```

Comment: What if I want to return multiple types(like String,Int)? getting error : org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1

Comment: That could be helpful, but I am working with mysql not Oracle.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do that is return the out parameter as part of the returning parameters
(relevant only if you have access to the store procedures).
jest add a store procedure like the following one

```
create procedure myProcedure_only_in_parms (
   in in_Id int)
begin
call myProcedure(in_id,@out_Id) ;
select @out_id
END;
```

after done that it quite simple to use it with Hibernet in the following way

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"CALL myProcedure_only_in_parms (:in_Id)")
.setParameter("in_id", 123);
List result = query.list();
```

The result contains the out parameter,
if you want return multiply parameters you can add it by doing 
select @parm1,@parm2,... ,@parmn 

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
        ProcedureCall query = session.createStoredProcedureCall("dbo.sp_getorderlistbyparam",BasicResult.class);
        query.registerParameter("search_text",String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(searchText);
        query.registerParameter("membership_nbr",String.class, 
        query.registerParameter("is_debug",Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(0);
        query.registerParameter("result_count",Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        basicResults = (List<BasicResult>) query.getResultList();
        ProcedureOutputs procedureOutputs = query.getOutputs();
        parameterMap.put("totalOrderCnt" ,(Integer) procedureOutputs.getOutputParameterValue("result_count"));
```

Comment: it will be good to explain what and how these script works. It will help future user to get better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
@PersistenceContext 
private EntityManager entitymanager;
     @Override
            public String function(int id, int emp_id, String letype, String days, Date fromdate, Date todate, String reason,
                    String backup, int user_id) {

                //Session session = entitymanager.unwrap(Session.class);

                StoredProcedureQuery  applyLeave = entitymanager.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_apply_leave");

                applyLeave.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_emp_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_letype", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_days", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_fmdate", Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_todate", Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_reason", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_backper", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_user_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("error_msg", String.class, ParameterMode.INOUT);


                applyLeave.setParameter("p_id", id);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_emp_id" , emp_id);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_letype" , letype);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_days" , days);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_fmdate" , fromdate);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_todate" , todate);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_reason" , reason);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_backper" , backup);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_user_id" , user_id);
                applyLeave.setParameter("error_msg", new String("error_msg"));
                //applyLeave.executeUpdate();

                String error_msg = (String) applyLeave.getOutputParameterValue("error_msg");
                return error_msg;

            }
```

here i have autowired entitymanager and configured hibernate Persistence in config package

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public String generateVoucherNumber(ExpenseHeaderDTO expenseHeaderDTO) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    ProcedureCall query =  session.createStoredProcedureCall("voucher_number");
            query.registerParameter(
                "module", String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue("EMPLOYEE_EXPENSE");
            query.registerParameter(
                "voucherNumber", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

    ProcedureOutputs procedureResult=query.getOutputs();
    String voucherNumber= (String) procedureResult.getOutputParameterValue("voucherNumber");
    return voucherNumber;
}
```

Refer above example

Answer (score -1):

```
    just cal normal way but store response out param 
in Object[] and we can also get multiple response value in Onject[]

    Object[] respnseCode = (Object[])session.createSQLQuery(
    "CALL myProcedure_only_in_parms (:in_Id)")
    .setParameter("in_id", 123);
    List result = query.list();

    sysout("out_Id"+respnseCode[0]);
```

Answer (score -3):

ResultSet rs1=null;

```
     ArrayList<Lookup_master> list=new ArrayList<Lookup_master>();

     CallableStatement cStmt;


    try {

        cStmt = hibernateConfiguration.dataSource().getConnection()
                    .prepareCall("{call SP_ADVSER_LOOKUPMASTER(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

        cStmt.setString(1,lookup_master.getLookup_code());
        cStmt.setString(2,lookup_master.getLookup_type());
        cStmt.setString(3,lookup_master.getLookup_name());
        cStmt.setString(4,lookup_master.getMeaning());
        cStmt.setString(5,request.getParameter("start_date"));
        cStmt.setString(6,request.getParameter("end_date"));

        cStmt.registerOutParameter(7, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cStmt.executeQuery();


        rs1 = (ResultSet) cStmt.getObject(7);


        while (rs1.next()) {

            Lookup_master lookup_master1=new Lookup_master();

            lookup_master1.setLookup_id(rs1.getInt(1));
            lookup_master1.setLookup_code(rs1.getString(2));
            lookup_master1.setLookup_type(rs1.getString(3));
            lookup_master1.setLookup_name(rs1.getString(4));
            lookup_master1.setMeaning(rs1.getString(5));
            lookup_master1.setStart_date(rs1.getDate(6));
            lookup_master1.setEnd_date(rs1.getDate(7));

             list.add(lookup_master1);
            System.out.println(lookup_master1.getLookup_id());

        }



    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     return  list;
 }
```

Comment: cStmt = hibernateConfiguration.dataSource().getConnection()
                    .prepareCall("{call SP_ADVSER_LOOKUPMASTER(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");