# Calling Oracle procedures in java

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a procedure in oracle to decrypt password with one in and one out parameters. I am trying to call in my java program as follows but it shows SQLGrammarException. I am new to Oracle and trying this for first time. Sorry I Searched in internet but I didn't find anything.
In SQL server I was using like this.

```
Iterator it = hibernateSession.createSQLQuery("EXEC DAN_DANAPP_DECRYPPWD '" + username.getText().trim() + "'").list().iterator();
```

it was working in SQL server. When I tried the same in Oracle it was not working. Can anyone spot me out what mistake I had attempted.

My Oracle procedure is as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DAN0703.DAN_DANAPP_DECRYPPWD 
(EMPNO IN VARCHAR2,P_STRING OUT VARCHAR2)
IS

 P_KEY_STRING  VARCHAR2(12) := 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
 P_ERROR_NO NUMBER;
 RAW_KEY RAW(128);
 DECRYPTED_RAW RAW(2048);

BEGIN

 RAW_KEY := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(P_KEY_STRING);

 select USER_PASSWD into P_STRING  FROM MENU_USER  WHERE USER_ID = EMPNO  AND 
 USER_FLAG = 'O' and (USER_DISABLE_FLAG='N' or USER_DISABLE_FLAG='V');

 DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.DESDECRYPT(INPUT => P_STRING, KEY => RAW_KEY,  
 DECRYPTED_DATA => DECRYPTED_RAW );

 P_STRING := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DECRYPTED_RAW);

END;
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: are you using hibernate framework or simple JDBC ? and what is `loginsession ` ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. Yes I am using hibernate framework and it is my session variable.

Comment: createSQLQuery seems to be deprectaed https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createSQLQuery-java.lang.String-

Comment: I am using version 4.3 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that:

```
Iterator it = loginsession.createSQLQuery("CALL DAN_DANAPP_DECRYPPWD(:EMPNO)")
.setParameter("EMPNO", username.getText().trim()).list().iterator();
```

**EDIT**

A link explaining of to deal with out parameters with JPA:

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/

Comment: I tried but follwoing error is coming. java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DAN_DANAPP_DECRYPPWD'

Comment: That's because your stored procedure waits also for a `OUT` parameter (`P_STRING`). This cannot be passed via the `.setParameter` method. Consider refactoring your stored procedure not to require this `OUT` parameter. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349227/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-hibernate-having-both-in-and-out-parameters

Comment: So no ways to get OUT parameter in Java??

Comment: Maybe this: https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/03/22/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/

Answer (score 1):

In oracle to call a procedure you have to code:

```
loginSession.createSQLQuery("CALL DAN0703.DAN_DANAPP_DECRYPPWD(:username)")
    .setParameter("username", username.getText().trim());
```