# How to call MySQL stored procedure with output parameter in spring boot using hibernate entitymanager

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to achieve calling a stored procedure with out parameter using Hibernate `createNativeQuery` method. Is there any way to achieve passing parameter using `setParameter` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a Stored Procedure from Hibernate having both IN and OUT parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349227/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-hibernate-having-both-in-and-out-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     @PersistenceContext 
private EntityManager entitymanager;
     @Override
            public String function(int id, int emp_id, String letype, String days, Date fromdate, Date todate, String reason,
                    String backup, int user_id) {

                //Session session = entitymanager.unwrap(Session.class);

                StoredProcedureQuery  applyLeave = entitymanager.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_apply_leave");

                applyLeave.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_emp_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_letype", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_days", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_fmdate", Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_todate", Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_reason", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_backper", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_user_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("error_msg", String.class, ParameterMode.INOUT);


                applyLeave.setParameter("p_id", id);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_emp_id" , emp_id);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_letype" , letype);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_days" , days);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_fmdate" , fromdate);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_todate" , todate);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_reason" , reason);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_backper" , backup);
                applyLeave.setParameter("p_user_id" , user_id);
                applyLeave.setParameter("error_msg", new String("error_msg"));
                //applyLeave.executeUpdate();

                String error_msg = (String) applyLeave.getOutputParameterValue("error_msg");
                return error_msg;

            }
```